# why is onResume code called before layout display?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have two activities, `A` and `B`; A's layout  contains a button `ABut` to call `B`. i want to execute a code after `B`'s layout is completely rendered (components visible to the user). From the [Android life Cycle Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) i'm supposed to put that code in `onResume` method. That's what i did but the code is still executed before the layout is rendered. To check that that code is effectively executed before `B`'s layout is displayed, i did put a delay of 4s in that code and the result is: upon `ABut` click, **nothing happens during 4 seconds then `B`'s layout is displayed** : which confirms that the code inside onResume is effectively called before the layout display!!!.

Here i give you parts of the code:

A's code:

```
...
public void onAButClick(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BActivity_.class));
}
...
```

B's code:

```
...
 @Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.i(TAG,"Data Loaded");       

}
...
```

Can somebody tell me why is the code inside onResume method executed before layout display and how can i make it being executed just after the view is completely rendered?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In on Resume try to put handler instead of thread.sleep

```
super.onResume();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.i(TAG,"data loaded");
            }
        }, 4000);
```

dont forget to declare hander in your activity (B), i whope this work

Answer (score -1):

> nothing happens during 4 seconds then B's layout is displayed

It is due to you call `Thread.sleep(4000);` in main thread so it has been frozen for 4000 mini second.

> i want to execute a code after B's layout is completely rendered
>   (components visible to the user)

1. Declare `View rootView;` associate with your root layout.
2. In your `onCreate`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       rootView = findViewById(R.id.root);
       ViewTreeObserver vto = rootView.getViewTreeObserver();
       vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                rootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                // now your layout is completely rendered
               // execute your code here
            }
      });
   }
   ```

Hope it help!

Comment: i do know that the screen freezes because of the Thread.sleep, its done on purpose. Just to test that the code under onResume is kind of executed before the scree is displayed.

Comment: It's ok, but can you tell me the reason for down vote?. My solution depend on your statement

Comment: i am not the one who down-voted you... anyway, i didn't test your solution cause it doesn't reply to my question. i want to understand the weird behavior.